# Is it possible to scrape a "dynamical webpage" with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am currently begining to use beautifulsoup to scrape websites, I think I got the basics even though I lack theoretical knowledge about webpages, I will do my best to formulate my question.

What I mean with dynamical webpage is the following: a site whose HTML changes based on user action, in my case its collapsible tables.

I want to obtain the data inside some "div" tag but when you load the page, the data seems unavalible in the html code, when you click on the table it expands, and the "class" of this "div" changes from something like "something blabla collapsible" to "something blabla collapsible active" and this I can scrape with my knowledge.

Can I get this data using beautifulsoup? In case I can't, I thought of using something like selenium to click on all the tables and then download the html, which I could scrape, is there an easier way?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Selenium is probably your best bet, then use `driver.page_source` to grab the HTML. If you want more concrete advice it'd be helpful to see some code.

Comment: problem is when page uses `JavaScript/AJAX` to load data. If you know which url is used by `JavaScript/AJAX` to get data then you can use `urllib/requests` to get this data too. You can use `DevTools` in `Chrome/Firefox` to manually find this url and then you can use it in Python code. But you have to know HTTP, DevTools, sometimes JavaScript, XPath, etc. BTW: Turn off JavaScript in browser and load page and you will see what urllib/requests (and BS) see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrape a series of tables with BeautifulSoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345085/scrape-a-series-of-tables-with-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If the data is already loaded when the page loads, then the data is available to scrape, it's just in a different element, or being hidden. If the click event triggers loading of the data in some way, then no, you will need Selenium or another headless browser to automate this.

Beautiful soup is **only** an HTML parser, so whatever data you get by requesting the page is the only data that beautiful soup can access.