# Scraping an ID with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract data from this site:

https://www.ultimatetennisstatistics.com/tournamentEvent?tournamentEventId=4073

I want the stats of a single match, e.g. the finals, that you can see it clicking in the blue icon.

[This is what I see when I do so:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb4uy.jpg)

So, I wrote this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla5/.0'}
URL = "https://www.ultimatetennisstatistics.com/tournamentEvent?tournamentEventId=4073"

page = requests.get(URL, headers= headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

stats = soup.find(id="matchStats-171140Overview")

print(stats)
```

But the result is "None". I don't understand why, because that id did exist. I want to get, e.g. the 3.1 %.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Typo in the code, try this ```stats = soup.find(id="matchStats-171140")```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I inspect that web page, I don't see an element with an id `matchStats-171140Overview`, but I do see an element with an id `matchStats-171140`. So I think Sushanth is right about that.

However, when I ran your code and printed `soup`, I couldn't find an element with the id `matchStats-171140`.

What worked was this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser') # page.text instead of page.content

stats = soup.find(id="matchStats-171140") # Took out 'Overview' from the id
```

`page` is a Requests response, and `.content` gives you the response in bytes. It may be causing you to lose the id attribute somehow.

See requests docs on [`.content`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) vs. [`.text`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content).

EDIT: I see the issue now. The element you want is not in the DOM until a user clicks the blue icon to show the popup. That's why Beautiful Soup can't find it. This thread might be what you're looking for: [Is it possible to scrape a "dynamical webpage" with beautifulsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732906/is-it-possible-to-scrape-a-dynamical-webpage-with-be)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! That ID gets something, but not what I want. I just actualized the post, now maybe is more clear. I tried .text and .content but in this case I get the same result with your ID and "None" with my ID. So the problem persist.

Comment: Got it. I edited my answer, hopefully it steers you in the right direction. Basically it might not be possible with just Beautiful Soup because this is a dynamic web page.